# Corollary to Nakayama Lemma

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

My problem came from understanding the proof of a corollary of Nakayama's Lemma on a local ring. The statement says

> Let $R$ be a local ring with the maximal ideal $I$ and $M$ a fg $R$ module. Suppose $\{x_1+IM,\cdots,x_n+IM\}$ is a generating set for $M/IM$ as a $R/I$ module then we can lift this set to be a generating set for $M$ as a $R$ module.

The vast majority of the proof was fine however I couldn't convince myself on this one point.

> Suppose $M'$ is the submodule generated by the lifted set. Then $M'+IM=M$ and so $I(M/M')=M/M'$

I couldn't convince myself why $I(M/M')=M/M'$ follows from $M'+IM=M$, the isomorphism theorem seems to have hit a dead end, could someone please explain it in a bit more detail?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you aware about the construction of $M/M'$ and what its elements are?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I see! Working with elements made sense to me! Thanks! (I was kind of hoping a more elegant way or showing this :) )